# Proof verification of continuous image of connected subset is connected

Tags: solution-verification, continuity, metric-spaces, connectedness

I was re reading rudin and came across a familiar theorem. I thought of a different proof but I'm unsure if it's correct.

Th. If $f$ is a continuous mapping from metric space $X$ to $Y$ and if $E$ is a connected subset if $X$ then $f(E)$ is connected.

My proof attempt:
Assume $f(E)$ disconnected $\implies f(E)=A \cup B$ for disjoint open nonempty sets $A,B \in Y$. Consider the preimages

$f^{-1}(f(E))=E=f^{-1}(A\cup B)=f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)$

But since $f$ is continuous the preimage of open sets $A$ and $B$ is open in $X$.

So we get $E$ as the union of two nonempty open sets. It's intersection must be empty because if $x\in f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)$ then $f(x)\in A\cap B$ but this was chosen to be empty.

So E is disconnected which is a contradiction.

Comment: $f^{-1}(f(E)) = E$ is not true in general. E.g., take $f : [-1, 1] \to [0, 1]$ to be $x \mapsto x^2$ and take $E = [0, 1]$.

Comment: Ah yes I thought I was missing something. I suppose the proof I gave could work if f is a homeomorphism between the topologies.

Comment: $f^{-1}(f(E)) = E$ for all $E$ iff $f$ is an injection. Your proof works in that case, which is a bit more general than requiring $f$ to be a homeomorphism ($X$ could have a finer topology than $Y$).